# SSRS does not recognize the .NET Framework Class library

Tags: reporting-services

Created a .NET Framework class library with strong name added an Nuget reference. 
Registered the .NET framework class library dll in GAC.
Added the reference from GAC path in SSRS reports file.

System.MethodAccessException is thrown.

Comment: I think we could use some more information about what you are trying to do.  It sounds like you are trying to use a .NET Framework object in a report.  My first thought is "why would someone do that?".  Is this a report that you made, and put into SSRS (server)?  When you say "registered in the GAC", you mean the GAC of your SSRS server?  And where are you seeing this error?  from your app, or from the SSRS web interface or elsewhere?